# Convert a decimal rating (max of 5 w/ 0.1 increments) to a percentage

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I'm working on a star rating system and I need to convert my decimal values to a percentage % so I can use that as a width of the top layer.

The way this works is that both `span`'s are on top of each other. The top is colored grey, the bottom is colored orange. The closer the bottom `span` gets to 100% width (85px), the more "full" the stars look.

It all works as expected but now I need to convert my incoming `reviewStarRating` number to a percentage. The values of `reviewStarRating` can be 0 - 5 with 0.01 increments. So some examples of incoming `reviewStarRating` would be (0.4, 1.3, 2.8, 3.0, 4.2, 4.9, 5.0).

- 5.0 `reviewStarRating` would == 100%
- 4.0 `reviewStarRating` would == 80%
- 3.0 `reviewStarRating` would == 60%
- 2.0 `reviewStarRating` would == 40%
- 1.0 `reviewStarRating` would == 20%
- 0.0 `reviewStarRating` would == 0%

HTML

```
<div class="star-container">
    <span class="star-icon grey" [innerHTML]="icons"></span>
    <span class="star-icon orange" [ngStyle]="getCssWidth()" [innerHTML]="icons"></span>
</div>
```

JS / Angular Typescript

```
@Input() reviewCount: String;
@Input() reviewStarRating: String;
cssWidth: number = 0;
icon = '&#9733;';
icons = `${this.icon}${this.icon}${this.icon}${this.icon}${this.icon}`

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.calculateCssWidth();
}
public getCssWidth() {
  let styles = {
    'width': `${this.cssWidth.toString()}px`
  }
  return styles;
}
calculateCssWidth() {
  this.cssWidth = this.round(this.reviewStarRating);
  console.log(`${this.reviewStarRating} -> ${this.cssWidth}`);
}
round(num) {
  return Math.ceil((num+1)/10)*10;
}
```

CSS

```
.star-container {
     max-width: 140px;
     width: 85px;
     height: 20px;
     line-height: 20px;
}
 .star-container .star-icon {
     font-size: 20px;
     position: relative;
}
 .star-container .star-icon.orange {
     color: #f37a1f;
     top: -22px;
     display: block;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .star-container .star-icon.grey {
     color: #e3e3e3;
}
.star-container:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function toPercentage(num: number) : string {
    return `${num / 5 * 100}%`;
}
```

Comment: This was very close! Thanks. I had to change the `100` to `85` since the `div` i was working within was `85px` wide. That made it so if the `num` was 5.0 i would get a width of `85px`

Comment: Thats if you are trying to give it value in pixels. as for me better practice will be to give the value in percentage, and to 100. (so `100% will be `85px` in case the container is `85px` wide)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Yosef for helping me get most of the way there. This was the solution I was looking for. The 85 is because the width of the div I was working in was 85px wide. So if i put in a 5.0 number, i wanted 85px to be the max it would return.

```
toPercentage(num) {
   return (num / 5 * 85);
}
```