# Why isn´t my top span coloring until covering the whole given width?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Using the code provided in this link [Convert a decimal rating (max of 5 w/ 0.1 increments) to a percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62523634/convert-a-decimal-rating-max-of-5-w-0-1-increments-to-a-percentage), I'm implementing an star rating system. The problem is that the starts are only filling whole numbers. For example, if my number is 2.3 the orange stars only fill until 2 even though its width is being given correctly taking into account the 0.3.

HTML

```
 <div class="star-container">
     <span class="star-icon grey" [innerHTML]="icons"></span>
     <span
          class="star-icon orange"
          [ngStyle]="getCssWidth()"
          [innerHTML]="icons"
          ></span>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
  .star-container {
  max-width: 140px;
  width: 85px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  }

  .star-container .star-icon {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  }

 .star-container .star-icon.orange {
  color: #f37a1f;
  top: -22px;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  }

  .star-container .star-icon.grey {
   color: #e3e3e3;
  }

  .star-container:not(:last-child) {
   margin-right: 5px;
  }
```

Typescript

```
   cssWidth: number = 0;
   icon = "&#9733;";
   icons = `${this.icon}${this.icon}${this.icon}${this.icon}${this.icon}`;

   ngOnInit() {
     this.calculateCssWidth();
   }

   public getCssWidth() {
   let styles = {
      width: `${this.cssWidth.toString()}px`
   };
      return styles;
   }

   calculateCssWidth() {
      let num = 2.7; //Number of stars
      this.cssWidth = this.getStars(num);
   }

   getStars(num) { 
      return (num / 5) * 85;
   }
```

[This image show how it is supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtfmb.png)

[This one shows how it actually looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QceNJ.png)

As you can see, even though the second span in the html does receive the correct width, it does not color to the end, instead it just fills it if it can fill the whole stars.

Answer (score 0):

First I believe there is a typo in your CSS as you are missing a period from the first line of CSS if the intention is that this is a class and not an element.

Second I think the math is wrong for the getStars. [Changing this value to 100 gets things to work as expected in this stackbliz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yrjn1a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

So change CSS to:

```
.star-container {
  max-width: 140px;
  width: 85px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

and adjust your getStars function:

```
getStars(num) {
    return (num / 5) * 100;
  }
```

EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:

The root cause of your issue is that while you have defined your container component as 85px, your sub-components are in fact 100px due to total width of icons.

[image]

If your intention is to make the width dynamic you are better off using percentages as discussed in the thread you reference in your question.

Comment: The thing with the math is that the total width of the container is 85. With 100 if I do (4.5 / 5) * 100 it'll say the percentage is 90 but that number is what I take for the width of the orange stars so it'll fill the 85 width and add 5 stars even though it shouldn't

Comment: And yeah sorry the . in star-container was a mistake when doing the copy paste of the code

Comment: See updated answers